# Как можно забрать информацию с чужого сайта на свой методами программирования?

Tags: веб-программирование, php, html

Например есть данные о погоде на яндексе, в которой динамическая информация, забрать себе на сайт!

Comment: Очень просто. Юзаешь специальную программу, которая делает скриншоты, задаешь время. Ну, и потом выкладываешь к себе на сайт... Можно в виде gif картинки

Comment: это шутка надеюсь?

Comment: данные в текстовом формате, и чтобы всё было автоматизированно

Comment: серьезный ответ на серьезный вопрос =)

Comment: Неа, нужно обращаться к фотоаппарату, направленному на монитор каждые N секунд

Comment: я в вэбе не шарю, но по-моему нужно просто получить страницу в виде html, а потом парсить  и вытаскивать нужную тебе информацию.

Comment: >!!!данные в текстовом формате, и чтобы всё было автоматизированно!!!

поменьше эмоций, глядишь, и поможет кто. Вам тут слуг нет

Comment: @Firespirit ну это уже крайний случай, молоток.

Answer (score 4):

Даже и не знаю, что сказать если конкретно погода то для этго и многого другого в яндексе есть апи http://api.yandex.ru/
И у многих других сервисов есть апи которое просто надо читать и делать как в инструкции.
Погодный информер:http://pogoda.yandex.ua/kyiv/informer/

А если касается какого-то уникального и специального контента с како-гото другого сайта который не предоставляет апи, то надо писать парсер который будет информацию собирать

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите [тут](http://maarkus.ru/prognoz-pogody-dlya-sajta-cherez-api-yandeksa/)

Answer (score -1):

Ну в принципе у некоторых есть виджеты с кодом, который можно скопировать себе на сайт. Facebook так кнопки добавляет нанапример. В принципе, многие из них упрощены до загрузки скрипта и немного разметки где именно "воткнуть" кнопку/галерею/погоду. Минус в том, что это всё действует на стороне клиента.

То есть идём на сайт, ищем, есть ли у них уже такое, если не находится - гуглим embed <название сервиса> и, если повезёт, находим инструкцию, как.

Также можно использовать API, как советуют другие, тогда придётся писать свои скрипты которые к этому всему обращаются и так далее, но зато можно будет использовать полученную информацию на сервере. Тогда соответственно гуглим <название сервиса> api <на чём программируем>. Иногда везёт и уже имеется библиотека, если нет - курим доки на API и вручную всё.